# How to fit a longitudinal GAM mixed model (GAMM)

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, generalized-additive-model

I have repeated measurements of individuals, like this

```
y  |  id  | time  |  V1   | V2
100    1       1     23.2   0.8
88     1       2     22.6   0.9
98     2       1     10.6   1.1
83     2       2     11.1   1.3
```

`y` is a continous outcome variable, `id` is the patient id, `time` is the time point of oberservation and `V1` and `V2` are covariates.

In this data example we have 2 patients that have 2 observations each, one at time 1 and another one at time 2.

My real data sets has hundreds of patients (ids) and 2-5 observations (time) for each patient.

I now know that the effect of `V1` on `y` is non-linear and what to model this with a GAM.

In the `mgcv` package there is a function called `gamm()`. In my example, I use it like this:

```
m <- gamm(y ~ s(V1) + V2 + time ,family=gaussian,
          data=dat,random= ~(time|id))
```

Is this correct?
Does this model integrate the fact that `V1` can change over time for each individual?

Comment: I suggest to implement random effects within `gam` as a smoother instead, i.e., `bs = "re"` or even `bs = "fs"`. Such a model is easier to handle since it doesn't consist of two models internally as `gamm` does. Anyway, what does "V1 can change over time for each individual"  mean exactly? Is `V1` perhaps strongly collinear with `time`?

Comment: @Roland how would I formulate this using `gam` ? Do I still get parameter estimates for V2 ? V1 is a variable like BMI that may be strongly correlated with its observation at the previous time point.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "may be strongly correlated with its observation at the previous time point"? This suggests a lagged effect, but you include `V1` as a predictor of `y` contemporaneously (unless you lagged it yourself?). If the effect of `V1` is intended to vary with `time`, then your model isn't accounting for that. Some further explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @GavinSimpson let's assume `V1` is BMI and I want to integrate individual BMI changes over time into the model

Comment: If the effect of BMI==1, or BMI==10 stays the same over time, then `s(BMI)` will include the effect of BMI on the response as the recorded BMI changes over time. The effect of smooth effect of BMI won't be correlated with time (the smooth of time will look quite different to the smooth of BMI), but the smooth of time will explain temporal variation in the response not captured by the other terms in the model.

Comment: If you want the effect of BMI==1 at time t=1 to be different from the effect of BMI=1 at time t=100, then no, the specification used currently is not going to account for that sort of time variation.

Comment: @GavinSimpson How would I add the later? I could add a fixed effect interaction BMI*time but I would want something on the individual level too

Comment: @spore234 the main effects and interaction would be `te(BMI, time, k = c(a,b))` with suitable values for a and b if needed. This is the smooth equivalent of `BMI * time`. If you want to decompose this, then: `s(BMI) + s(time) + ti(BMI, time)`. If you want the linear effect of `BMI` to vary smoothly with time, i.e. a varying coefficient model, then `s(time, by = BMI)` assuming BMI is coded as a numeric variable. It really depends on what you want to represent in the model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What @Roland is getting at is to use a random spline basis for the `time` by `id` random part. So your model would become:

```
m <- gam(y ~ s(V1) + V2 + s(time, id, bs = 'fs'),
         family=gaussian, data=dat, method = "REML")
```

This model says that the effect of `time` is smooth and varies by `id`, with a separate smooth being estimated for each `id` but each smooth is assumed to have the same wiggliness (a single smoothness penalty is estimated for all the `time` smoothers) but can differ in shape.

To estimate a separate "global" effect the model could be

```
m <- gam(y ~ s(V1) + V2 + s(time) + s(time, id, bs = 'fs'),
         family=gaussian, data=dat, method = "REML")
```

If you want similar models but where each smooth can have different wiggliness as well as shape, then the `by` smoothers can be used:

```
## without a "global" effect
m <- gam(y ~ s(V1) + V2 + s(id, bs = 're') + s(time, by = id),
         family=gaussian, data=dat, method = "REML")

## with a "global" effect
m <- gam(y ~ s(V1) + V2 +
         s(id, bs = 're') + s(time) + s(time, by = id, m = 1),
         family=gaussian, data=dat, method = "REML")
```

The `m=1` means that the smoother uses a penalty on the squared first derivative, which penalises departure from a flat function of no effect. As this is on the subject specific smooths, the model is penalising deviations from the "global" smooth.

Some colleagues and I have described these models in some detail in a paper submitted to PeerJ, which is available as a [preprint](https://doi.org/10.7287/peerj.preprints.27320v1). A new version in response to reviewers comments should be up in a few days (we've submitted it to the journal).

Comment: Nice manuscript. Looks like a useful reference for a paper's methods section.