# Building the right GAM model. Struggling with the jump from lmer()

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-additive-model, large-data

I have I have no experience with `gam()` but I think this is the right way to model my data.

Sample data:

```
tibble [9,286 × 9] (S3:
tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Fiscode   : Factor w/ 21406 levels
"120097","502468",..: 27 31 31 53 53 62
62 62 64 64 ...
 $ Status    : Factor w/ 4 levels
"O","E","R","D": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Nationcode: Factor w/ 112 levels
"CHN","SWE","NOR",..: 8 10 10 16 16 22 22
22 16 ...
$ Gender    : Factor w/ 2 levels "M","W":
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Birthyear : num [1:9286] 2002 1999
1999 2001 2001 ...
$ Season    : num [1:9286] 2020 2020 2020
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 ...
 $ Age       : int [1:9286] 18 21 21 19
19 20 20 20 19 19 ...
 $ Discipline: Factor w/ 4 levels
"DHpos","GSpos",..: 3 2 3 3 1 2 3 1
$World_R   : int [1:9286] 231 138 178 217
180 188 184 187 268 251 ...
```

The data includes the world ranking for the top 300 skiers (male and female) in the world across all four alpine disciplines.  Right now I have gathered the yearly ranking from the last four years, but the plan is to end up with somewhere around 15 to 20 years. That's why I think `bam()` would be the best.

If I use `lmer()`, I would fit the model like this (Fiscode = ID):

```
lmer_mod <- lmer(World_R ~ Age + Gender + Discipline 
             + (1 + Discipline |Fiscode / Nationcode), 
 data = test)
```

What I got so far with `bam()`:

```
gam_mod <- bam(World_R ~ s(Age, by = Discipline) + s(Fiscode, bs = "re"), data = test, method = "fREML", family = scat)
```

I tried it first with `family = poisson`, but the residuals in the QQ plot were extremely heavy tailed.

My question is:
How do I fit the smooths for each Discipline and Gender. Also, how do I show how the skiers improve their world ranking for each year during their career. I also struggle with how to fit the nested random effects in `gam()`.

Comment: I recommend reading this paper: https://peerj.com/articles/6876/

Comment: @Roland, thank you:)

Comment: Can you explain why `Fiscode` needs to be nested and not crossed? Perhaps it's not that common but athletes do change the country for whom they compete.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you for the question. you're right athletes can change countries during their careers, but in Alpine skiing there are only a handful of cases where the athletes change the country they represent. There are some numbers on this but I know that it's not very common in skiing however I know about 5 cases in this data set.

Comment: @GavinSimpson The reason I think they are nested is because there are often some races that there is easier to improve their world ranking. For example in nations where the snow conditions are more stable and there are very good athletes It's easier to get a better world ranking. for example if you are from one of these nations I would guess that it's easier to be among the top 300 skiers in the world but that don't necessarily mean that you will be one of the top 30 skiers in the world. You just had a bit of luck because you competed in the place where it's a better chance to compete with the

Comment: @SimenLeitheTajet that implies an interpretation of `NationCode`; what is this? I assumed it was nationality of the skier but perhaps it is something different? If it is nationality, then you can accommodate the crossed random effect if you code the individuals correctly

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes it is that, great thank you!

Comment: @GavinSimpson One question I struggle a little bit to understand the bs = "sz" command on the last models. Does this inform the model that I have repeated measured like the s(Fiscode, bs = "re") does?

Comment: @SimenLeitheTajet Yeah, sorry; I was keeping the models simple; if you just want a different intercept per skier, add that smooth to the model specification I show at the end with the multiplier `"sz"` smooths.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I understand !thank you :)

Comment: @SimenLeitheTajet Also, don't ignore my comment at the start of my answer on choosing an appropriate response for ranks. Its not immediately clear that the approach you are taking is appropriate for rankings.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes I know it's not that easy, I'm thinking about going for ocat for ordered categorical data, and mutate a new Y variable for like 8-10 levels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not immediately clear to me why you went with `scat()` in the end; that distribution allows for both positive and negative ranks, if the response is the ranking. Likewise, the `poisson()` you used originally is for integer counts, while ranks are somewhat different. I'm not sure what the best approach to use here would be.

Aside from that not so small problem, the specification of the linear predictor is a little easier.

Say you want smooths per gender, age, and discipline, then *one* way to get that would be to create a factor that is the interaction of those two categorical variables

```r
library("dplyr")
libray("forcats")
test <- test |>
  mutate(gd = fct_cross(Gender, Discipline, keep_empty = TRUE))
```

and then use that in a factor-by model

```r
m <- bam(World_R ~ gd + s(Age, by = gd) + s(Fiscode, bs = "re"),
         data = test, method = "fREML", family = ...)
```

— noting that you *must* specify the group means via a parametric factor effect as shown — or, if you want to treat the `gd` factor as random, you could do use the `fs` basis

```r
m <- bam(World_R ~ s(Age, gd, bs = "fs") + s(Fiscode, bs = "re"),
         data = test, method = "fREML", family = ...)
```

in which case one doesn't need the group mean parametric factor effect as the `fs` basis includes these group means as a random intercept.

However, such a model may not be very parsimonious; it is unlikely that the smooth "effect" of age on the ranking varies that much across disciplines for example, and we wouldn't expect male and female skiers to be *that* different either. In that situation, it can be beneficial to fit "average" smooth effects and then smooth deviations or group-specific smooths. This is the focus of our HGAM paper that @Roland directed you to in the comments.

For example, to have an average smooth effect of age, plus gender-specific smooths of age, plus discipline-specific smooths age, we might use the following model

```r
m <- bam(World_R ~
           s(Age) +                                      # S1
           s(Age, Gender, bs = "sz") +                   # S2
           s(Age, Discipline, bs = "fs", by = Gender),   # S3
         data = test, method = "fREML", family = ...)
```

I have indicated the three smooths by a label `S1`, etc and justify the choices behind the representation below.

1. `S1` is the average smooth effect of age, over the entire data set. This would capture, for example, the general tendency for the world ranking to increase, reach a peak, and then decline again as a skier ages.
2. `S2` is a difference smooth, parametrised in such a way as to be orthogonal to the average smooth of age. This would describe the *smooth* differences between the "average" age effect and the smooth effects for each gender.
3. `S3` is a random factor smooth term, with a smooth of age for each discipline, which are allowed to differ by gender. I suggest modelling this more like a random effect because one could think of many disciplines from which *the* disciplines in the FIS rankings are drawn, and there are likely quite a few disciplines, but they all have roughly the same wiggliness, but different shapes — I wouldn't expect the smooth effect of age to be really wiggly for the slalom and really smooth for the downhill events for example.

As the `S3` term is fully penalised and the `S1` and `S2` terms are orthogonal by design of the `"sz"` basis, it shouldn't be a problem that you have multiple smooths of the same covariate `age`. If you do have difficulties, adding `m = 1` to the `S3` smooths might help, but I wouldn't advise it out of the gate.

Of course, there are different ways to reprameterise this model. An obvious one is to not estimate an average smooth, in which case we might have:

```r
m <- bam(World_R ~ Gender
           s(Age, by = Gender) +                         # S2
           s(Age, Discipline, bs = "fs", by = Gender),   # S3
         data = test, method = "fREML", family = ...)
```

But as I now see that you use only four disciplines, an alternative to representing the smooth effects of age by Discipline would be:

```r
m <- bam(World_R ~
           s(Age) +                                      # S1
           s(Age, Gender, bs = "sz") +                   # S2
           s(Age, Discipline, bs = "sz") +               # S3
           s(Age, Gender, Discipline, bs = "sz"),        # S4
         data = test, method = "fREML", family = ...)
```

where we build up the effects as smooth deviations from the average smooth (`S1`), first with first order interactions (`S2` and `S3`) and finally a second order interaction.

If you want each of the smooths in a given term (`S2`, `S3` etc) to share the same smoothing parameter, then you can `id = 1` to that term.

There's likely not much point in going through all the possibilities; the HGAM paper describes the general ideas and ways to specify the models (although it is missing the `"sz"` basis as that wasn't available in *mgcv* at the time of writing.)

---

## Nested random effects in GAMs

This whole difference between nested, crossed, random effects goes away if you code your factor variables appropriately.

Here's a reproducible example:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("lme4")
library("mgcv")

data(Oxide, package = "nlme")
Oxide <- mutate(Oxide, Wafer2 = factor(paste0(Lot, Wafer)))
```

In the last line I recode the original `Wafer` variable (which only takes values 1, 2, 3) to include the `Lot` information; wafer 1 on lot 1 is not the same wafer as wafer 1 on lot 2. We make this distinction clear by recoding the data.

Next I fit several models, first with `lmer()` amd finally `gam()` to show how the original coding needs a nested random effect `(1|Lot/Wafer)` but once we use the unambiguous coding in `Wafer2`, it doesn't matter which form we use, we get the same model fits and hence this is the correct way to fit a nested random effect with `gam()`:

```r
lmer_0 <- lmer(Thickness ~ 1 + (1|Lot/Wafer), data = Oxide, REML = TRUE)
lmer_1 <- lmer(Thickness ~ 1 + (1|Lot/Wafer2), data = Oxide, REML = TRUE)
lmer_2 <- lmer(Thickness ~ 1 + (1|Lot) + (1|Wafer2), data = Oxide, REML = TRUE)
gam_1  <- gam(Thickness ~ 1 + s(Lot, bs = "re") + s(Wafer2, bs = "re"),
              data = Oxide, method = "REML")
```

So we have

- `lmer_0`, a `lmer()` model in *nested* form using the original coding for `Wafer`
- `lmer_1`, a `lmer()` model in *nested* form using the unambiguous coding for `Wafer`, `Wafer2`
- `lmer_2`, a `lmer()` model in *crossed* form using the unambiguous coding for `Wafer`, `Wafer2`, and
- `gam_1`, a GAM version of the model using the unambiguous coding of `Wafer`, `Wafer2`

If we now extract the variance components of all these models, we can see that they are exactly the same

```r
r$> VarCorr(lmer_0)
 Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
 Wafer:Lot (Intercept)  5.9888 
 Lot       (Intercept) 11.3980 
 Residual               3.5453 

r$> VarCorr(lmer_1)
 Groups     Name        Std.Dev.
 Wafer2:Lot (Intercept)  5.9888 
 Lot        (Intercept) 11.3980 
 Residual                3.5453 

r$> VarCorr(lmer_2)
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Wafer2   (Intercept)  5.9888 
 Lot      (Intercept) 11.3980 
 Residual              3.5453 

r$> gratia::variance_comp(gam_1)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  component variance std_dev lower_ci upper_ci
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 s(Lot)       130.    11.4      6.39    20.3 
2 s(Wafer2)     35.9    5.99     4.06     8.82
3 scale         12.6    3.55     2.90     4.33
```

So, to avoid these kinds of quandaries, just recode your lower-level variable such that it includes the higher-level variable, just as I did for the `Wafer` variable by pasting the `Lot` and `Wafer` variables together.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer! this is really appreciated. Thank you for taking your time. This looks really good and I have to go through this carefully 

Answer (score 5):

I can break down what your function is doing piece by piece and you can decide if it models what you want.

- For `s(Age, by = Discipline)`, you are modeling the effect of age for each discipline group. It appears to have four levels. So you should have four independent splines, one for each level, and their main effect on World_R by age.
- For `s(Fiscode, bs = "re")`, you are modeling whatever Fiscode is as a random intercept. Keep in mind that this parameterization is very similar to how `lme4` treats this effect...<s>it models a linear relationship rather than a nonlinear one. That's not a real deal breaker, but if you want something with more specificity, you may want to consider the factor smooths with `bs = "fs"` instead.</s>  Warning: your variable Fiscode has a lot of levels. If you run `bam` on this, it will likely take a long time, as it is typically slower at estimating random effects than `lmer`.
- <s>This obviously doesn't do anything resembling nesting within groups. I believe that in order to achieve this, you would need to use the `gamm4` function from the `gamm4` package. I know for certain that `mgcv` does not allow correlated random slopes and intercepts either, only separate estimations of both. The good thing is that `gamm4` uses the same `lme4` syntax you are already accustomed to, but it comes at the cost of some functionality.</s> See Gavin's answer as my understanding was not correct.
- If you are looking at the standard residual output from a mixed model, don't. They are prone to having misleading and difficult to interpret output. Instead, consider using DHARMa residuals, which are documented [here.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html)
- For observing the effect of their performance over time, you can consider this example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391912/how-to-fit-a-longitudinal-gam-mixed-model-gamm), where they give an example of a factor varying by time within subjects.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Ideally I would like 8 splines, one for each level, and their main effect on World_R by age. Like Male SL, female SL ect. Fiscode is ID, so don't I need it as a random effect? I have read that gamm4 is most useful when the random effects are not .i.d. Thank you for the links I would look into them

Comment: Idk if thats true but I wouldn't really understand why that would be the case. It just treats ID variables as clusters like any other cluster in mixed models. For gender, you can use `by = Gender` in the splines you have to run a smooth for each gender.

Comment: `s(Fiscode, bs = "re")` isn't modelling anything as linear; if `Fiscode` is numeric then this term is all kinds of wrong, and if it's a factor, then you get a random intercept per skier, just as you would with `(1|Fiscode)`. Your comment on having to use `gamm4::gamm4()` to fit nested random effects isn't correct; see my updated answer for how to do this in `gam()` (or `bam()`).

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Fiscode is a factor, it is just the ID code, random intercept per skier is the goal :)

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks for clarifying, I have amended my answer accordingly